# I didnt find any time difference in event modeling in NODEJS using following example

Tags: node.js

I wrote a program using a blog reference, but i did not find any Time difference when i pass three request in a browser, it actually took almost 15 seconds to complete the last tab request and i believe NodeJS should satisfy the asynchronous way. it should complete the third browser tab request atleast with in 10 seconds right?

```
var http    =   require('http');
var server =    http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.write("Dog is Running \n ");
    setTimeout(function(){
        res.write("Dog Stop Running");
        res.end();
    },5000);
});
server.listen(80);
console.log("Server Listening in Port 80");
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the code doesn't block the main event loop.

But according to [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html), `setTimeout` callback might not be called in exact specified delay:

> It is important to note that your callback will probably not be called in exactly delay milliseconds - Node.js makes no guarantees about the exact timing of when the callback will fire, nor of the ordering things will fire in. The callback will be called as close as possible to the time specified

By the way, the reason you're getting those results might be related to many factors.